# Glitched Installation Process Screen

Tags: system-installation

Recently picked up a cheap rca windows 10 tablet from someone who was selling it and decided to try to convert it to linux due to specs. I am NOT trying to dual boot. I DO want to be it on linux soley, and will use the  erase option if I can get to it. The model number is w122sc24 according to the side

Linked imgur album should show these steps [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BS4k.jpg)
So far I was succesfully able to

- Create a bootable with rufus, using 18.04.3 lts
- Open bios and disable secure boot + set boot order to the usb
- Boot from and get to the grub black and white installation options

But after hitting either install  or try, the screen bugs out, again in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BS4k.jpg) and shows a mess. I would assume it's a graphics or driver issue. I would prefer ubuntu, but if there is no chance of this, then I am willing to try other distros, all help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after tinkering and looking around, I found this [article](https://medium.com/@realzedgoat/a-sorta-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-linux-on-32-bit-uefi-machines-d39b1d1961ec) on how to, and I figured out that this computer had a 32 bit uefi and 64 bit os capabilities.

So after reloading ubuntu onto the usb, I installed using safe graphics mode, and went into the kernel and changed the default ubuntu to nomodeset, so it always boots correctly and can work without a usb and disabling grub using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869678/how-can-i-disable-grub-from-appearing-after-selecting-ubuntu-in-refind-menu/869688). I can now now turn on and boot without grub and issues so far with windows completely removed from drive partitions.